# Import "keras.preprocessing.text" could not be resolved

Tags: python

I have an issue about Keras.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Embedding
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
```

There is an Error message if the code is executed,
`from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.preprocessing.text'`

Is there a solution for this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like text sub module is deprecated in latest version. https://pypi.org/project/keras/
[image]

I looked into the older versions something like 2.13.1 https://pypi.org/project/keras/2.13.1/#files

[image]

So download the older version and try again.
something like

```
pip install keras==2.13.1
```

Note: you may get compatibility issues with other libraries. If you get so then replace these text folder i newer version of the keras location.

Comment: Ah hey, quick question, the newer tensorflow is not compatible with the Keras 2.13.1. Is there any version that compatible with Keras 2.13.1 ?

Comment: I told you ...You may get compatibility issues. One thing you do is go to locations where all these libraries are installed and copy the text folder from older keras then install newer version and paste it this text folder inside the preprocessing folder.